# How to change the directory in a terminal from the ruby script?

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line-interface

I'm trying to build a CLI application that clones a git repository, creates a branch, and CD's into the newly cloned repository.
I'm able to achieve it, except for the part where I have to CD to the newly cloned repository.
What is the best way to change the directory in the terminal which is running my ruby script, through the said ruby script.

```
Dir.chdir "#{z}"
```

Which only changes the directory inside the script, but not at the terminal.

I have tried writing a secondary ruby script which performs the CD and calling it in backticks in my first ruby script, which has failed.

For the sake of testing, I tried to make the secondary ruby script which CDs to the previous directory.

**sidescript.rb**

```
puts "cd .."
```

and in my mainscript, I have,

```
`ruby ./sidescript.rb`
```

I'm aware that the ruby script execution forks the current terminal and starts to work on it, which is why commands like "system cd [my_path]" or exec don't work.

Is there possibility for some way to write a command on the current terminal to change the directory (rather than the ruby application's forked terminal)?

Comment: You can try writing a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, no, you can't. The only way you could (maybe) do this is by using the [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) system call, but even then, you'd need to use a custom terminal that would support it.

What you can do, however, is in the spirit of your `sidescript.rb`. But instead of executing it in your main script, you would have to do it directly from your terminal:

```rb
# sidescript.rb

puts 'cd my/new/path'
```

```sh
# In your terminal

$(ruby sidescript.rb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using like this

```
`cd path_to_directory && ruby sidescript.rb`
```